# Catching constraint violations in JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, try-catch, eclipselink, unique-constraint

Consider the following entity class, used with, for example, EclipseLink 2.0.2 - where the `link` attribute is not the primary key, but unique nontheless.

```
@Entity
public class Profile {  
  @Id 
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String link;

  // Some more attributes and getter and setter methods
}
```

When I insert records with a duplicate value for the `link` attribute, EclipseLink does not throw a `EntityExistsException`, but throws a `DatabaseException`, with the message explaining that the unique constraint was violated.

This doesn't seem very usefull, as there would not be a simple, database independent, way to catch this exception. What would be the advised way to deal with this?

A few things that I have considered are:

- Checking the error code on the `DatabaseException` - I fear that this error code, though, is the native error code for the database;
- Checking the existence of a `Profile` with the specific value for `link` beforehand - this obviously would result in an enormous amount of superfluous queries.

Comment: I have submitted a bug for this issue. Please vote for it so we can get this issue fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375745

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I insert records with a duplicate value for the link attribute, EclipseLink does not throw a EntityExistsException

Yes, and a JPA provider is not supposed to throw an [`EntityExistException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html) in that case, you won't get an [`EntityExistException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html) on something else than the primary key.

> (...) but throws a DatabaseException, with the message explaining that the unique constraint was violated.

This is very **WRONG** from EclipseLink, a JPA provider should throw a [`PersistenceException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html) or a subclass but certainly not a specific exception like [`o.e.p.e.DatabaseException`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/exceptions/DatabaseException.html). This is a bug and should be reported as such as I already mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519902/elegantly-handling-constraint-violations-in-ejb-jpa-environment/2522643#2522643).

> This doesn't seem very usefull, as there would not be a simple, database independent, way to catch this exception. What would be the advised way to deal with this?

Same answer as above, see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519902/elegantly-handling-constraint-violations-in-ejb-jpa-environment/2522643#2522643).

Comment: Since you mention EclipseLink in particular here: Do you know of other JPA providers who behave correctly?

Comment: @Hank Maybe the problem is fixed in recent versions, can't say. But to my knowledge, Hibernate does thrown a `PersistenceException` in such case.

Answer (score 2):

It's too bad they don't have a ConstraintViolationException in JPA. I've created a helper method to determine if the PersistenceException is a constraint violation for a given class - it is hibernate only though. I imagine there is a way to do it using other implementations.

```
protected Boolean isUniqueConstraintViolation(PersistenceException ex, Class entity) {

    if (((NonUniqueObjectException)ex.getCause()).getEntityName().equals(entity.getName())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```