# How to handle JPA unique constraint violations?

Tags: java, jpa, exception, constraints

When a unique constraint is violated, a `javax.persistence.RollbackException` is thrown. But there could be multiple reasons to throw a `RollbackException`. How can I find out that a unique constraint was violated?

```
try {
    repository.save(article);
}
catch(javax.persistence.RollbackException e) {
    // how to find out the reason for the rollback exception?
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How can I find out that a unique constraint was violated?

Exception are chained, you have to call `getCause()` recursively to get the provider specific exception (and maybe go down to the `SQLException`) to translate it into something your application can handle nicely for your user. The following will print the chain of exception:

```
for (t = e.getCause(); t != null; t = t.getCause()) {
    logger.debug("Exception:" + t);
}
```

For the exception handling and the "translation", you could do something like what Spring does (see the various `JpaDialect` classes, e.g. [`HibernateJpaDialect`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-orm/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaDialect.java?format=ok) to get an idea).

All this is not nice, this code won't be portable and finding what attribute(s) caused the violation won't be easy. This somehow confirms that there is no [elegant and portable way to handle constraint violations in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519902/elegantly-handling-constraint-violations-in-ejb-jpa-environment).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following :

If you are using spring framework then you can use :

`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`

If standard JPA following can be used

`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`

At sql level following can be used :

`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`

Comment: It did not help me. Can you confirm once?

Comment: You cannot talk about "standard JPA" and reference to hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.getCause()` to examine what caused the rollback.

Comment: ... and then parsing `getCause().getMessag()`?

Comment: That depends on what exception you will get. If it's an `SQLException,` check the error and SQLStatus. But some frameworks like Spring translate these to something more meaningful (`DataIntegrityViolationException`).

Answer (score 3):

This might very late for you but here's how I solved it for PostGres.

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {

            for (Throwable t = e.getCause(); t != null; t = t.getCause()) {

                if (PSQLException.class.equals(t.getClass())) {
                    PSQLException postgresException = (PSQLException) t;

                    // In Postgres SQLState 23505=unique_violation
                    if ("23505".equals(postgresException.getSQLState())) {
                        throw new CustomDataAlreadyExistsException("YourErrorCode", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new SomeOtherException("YourErrorCode2", e);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

compiler returns the exception ***SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException***, while trying to violate unique constraint.

Use the following catch block concept, to handle proper exceptions.

```
catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) 
{
  // Error message for integrity constraint violation
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Other error messages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think printing the stack trace will help you to know this. e.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
StringWriter writer=new StringWriter(); //remains the message from stack trace.
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
String message=writer.toString(); // gets the message of full stack trace.
```

And then view the information of exception.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do with the StackTrace? Parsing a string with the stack trace is somewhat ugly, but perhaps the only possibility.

Comment: And how would I know what field caused the constraint violation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch javax.persistence.PersistenceException.
Thrown exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.

Exception Message : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '893073116V-1234567' for key 'nic_account_no'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pin point the cause of constraint violation, is to **define the name of the constraint properly** in the first place:

#### Defining Unique Constraint:

Using `@UniqueConstraint` inside `@Table`, we can either define one column or multiple columns constraints, along with a **custom constraint name**:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }, name = "name_constraint"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "teamId", "orderIndex" }, name = "teamId_orderIndex_constraint")
})
public class Space {
    // .. other field omitted

    private String name;

    private Integer orderIndex;

    private Integer teamId;
}
```

JPA alter the constraint with our **custom name**:

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table space
       add constraint name_constraint unique (name)

Hibernate: 
    alter table space
       add constraint teamId_orderIndex_constraint unique (team_id, order_index)
```

#### Properly handle `DataIntegrityViolationException`:

Using `e.getMessage()`, we get result back, which contains the name of the constraint we defined above:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [space.name_constraint]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Then simply check if the result contains the name we defined:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;

try {
    repository.save(space);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {

    if(e.getMessage().contains("name_constraint")) {
        System.out.println("Unique name constraint violated");
    }

    if(e.getMessage().contains("teamId_orderIndex_constraint")) {
        System.out.println("Unique teamId_orderIndex constraints violated");
    }
}
```

Reference: [Defining Unique Constraints in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-unique-constraints#2-defining-unique-constraints)