# JDO handling unique constraint violations

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, unique-constraint

I have what I think is a common scenario in JDO.  I have a simple persistent class, say

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Person {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
    private long id;

    @Persistent
    @Unique
    private String name

    //constructor, equals, hashcode, etc...
}
```

Then I want to do a simple add, but throw a custom exception if the add fails because the unique constraint was violated

```
public void addPerson(String name) throws NotUniqueException {
    PersistenceManager pm = getPM();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

    try {
        tx.begin();

        Person toAdd = new Person(name);
        pm.makePersistent(toAdd);

        // how do I throw a NotUniqueException if the transaction fails due to 
        // "name" not being unique?

        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

How do I detect this error condition in JDO?  I'm fine with having to do a query first to check whether it will succeed, **as long as the check and add operation are atomic**.  I'm just new to JDO transactions and am not sure what guarantees I get if I do the query and checking in the transaction.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508976/228171), with JPA I would have to dig through the exception chain for the vender-specific cause exception and use that information.  Is that true of JDO?

Answer (score 0):

JDODataStoreException with nested datastore-specific exception, as per the JDO spec